# Interchanging integral and derivative operations in the context of Duhamel's formula

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, convolution, heat-equation

I'll give you the whole context: 
In solving the heat equation $u_t = ku_xx$ with bounds $u(x,0)=0, u(0,t)=0, u(l,t)=f(t)$, let $v(x,t)$ be the solution for the special case $f(t)=1$.

Use the Laplace transform to obtain Duhamel's formula:
$u(x,t)=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int_0^{t} f(s) v(x,t-s) \,ds$.

So I take the Laplace transform with respect to t och end up with (using the derivative transform + z/z trick + convolution transform) to get

$u(x,t) = \int_0^{t} f'(s) v(x,t-s) \,ds$.

My question: is this the answer I am looking for? Can I change the "order" of convolution and bring out the derivative?

Answer (score 1):

You could just as easily write

$$u(x,t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_0^t ds \, f(t-s) v(x,s) $$

which is equal to

$$u(x,t) = f(0) v(x,t) - f(t) v(x,0) + \int_0^t ds \, f'(t-s) v(x,s) $$

I assume you enforce $f(0)=0$ for continuity and that $v(x,0)=0$.  Therefore, you can write

$$u(x,t) = \int_0^t ds \, f'(s) v(x,t-s) $$

Note that we did not assert changing the order of differentiation and integration, but simply used the Fundamental theorem of calculus.